# Excel: How to extract a substring by only knowing the strings location?

Tags: string, excel

So basically, I am trying to attempt what the title says.

This may be easier to explain with an example:

I have a large string, such as - `spreadsheet`

```
              A              B         C
      ______________________________________
   1 |  spreadsheet     |  Number |  Letter
   2 |                  |    1    |    s
   3 |                  |    2    |    p
   4 |                  |    3    |    r
   5 |                  |    4    |    e
   6 |                  |    5    |    a
   7 |                  |    6    |    d
   8 |                  |    7    |    s
   9 |                  |    8    |    h
   10|                  |    9    |    e
   11|                  |    10   |    e
   12|                  |    11   |    t
```

Since the string `spreadsheet` has 11 characters, the numbers from 1 to 11 are created going down in a column. Each string that the number represents is then placed in the column next to it.

I searched for a function everywhere. Only found `MID` and `FIND`. Although both those functions require the knowledge of what string you are searching for exactly.

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is you input and what is your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(LEN($A$1)>=B2,MID($A$1,B2,1),"")
```

You could even get rid of column B by using the row function:

```
=IF(LEN($A$1)<=(ROW(C2)-ROW($C$1)),MID($A$1,ROW(C2)-ROW($C$1),1),"")
```

Comment: I require column B to be there since I need to know what position the characters are. Your first formula doesn't work :(

Comment: Mixed up `<` and  `>`. Try it again - it'll make sure it works, independent of the number of characters in the original word...

Answer (score 1):

The formula `=MID($A$1,B2,1)` filled down in your C column will give you the result.